# Drop shadow on rotated bitmap image

Tags: android, bitmap, shadow

Following is my code,

```
Paint mShadow = new Paint();
mShadow.setAntiAlias(true); 
mShadow.setShadowLayer(10, 10,10, Color.BLACK); 
canvas.save(); 
canvas.rotate((int)degrees,  100,  100);
canvas.drawBitmap(_image,200,200, mShadow);
canvas.restore();
```

Tried this but the shadow rotates as well.
How can you get the shadow to stay in same direction?

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
Paint mShadow = new Paint();
mShadow.setAntiAlias(true); 
mShadow.setShadowLayer(10, 10,10, Color.BLACK); 

canvas.drawRect(200, 200, 200+ (float) _image.getWidth(), 200 + (float) _image.getHeight(), mShadow);

canvas.save(); 
canvas.rotate((int)degrees,  100,  100);
canvas.drawBitmap(_image,200,200, null);
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: i tried the code but i'm getting the shadow doing what i want it to, but it's not taking the shape of the image but is a square.

Comment: yeah, that's true. I thought you wanted a rectangle. you could try [drawPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath) to get the shape you want.

Comment: i'm trying to draw a stored bitmap image with a shadow. you can do that with drawPath?

Comment: let me elaborate: in order to move the image independently of the shadow you need a second bitmap or drawable for the shadow. if you know the shape of the shadow, you can draw it with a path.